# How to form a slope equation for the polynomial trendline and calculate a R squared value for exponential trendline type with date time value

Tags: excel, date, graph

Tried to form a slope equation for the polynomial trendline type with the date-time type value, but I couldn't be able to form a slope equation. here is the expected output image for reference. I didn't get any solution can you please help me to form a polynomial equation.
Also, the R square value for exponential trendline type is different from the excel R square value for date-time type value when proceeding with the steps you gave above. Can you please help me with this issue?

**Polynomial slope equation:**

[image]

Comment: [HERE](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2019/01/16/excel-trendline-types-equations-formulas/) is a nice walk through on how to do it.

Comment: I just answered your other question. I think it might answer this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68548697/how-to-calculate-r-square-value-for-the-exponential-and-power-trendline-types/68853401#68853401